# MaxLinear XR21B1422 OTP programming

Tags: usb, otp

I have a MaxLinear XR21B1422 USB-UART bridge. I want to change the configurable GPIOs. Its possible to program the internal OTP through USB commands, but I have no idea how to do it. There is no description or application note available. The IC was originally from Exar. The company was taken over from MaxLinear. I have found old application notes from Exar which describes the programming using Exar tools like "Exar's OTP programming tool" or "Exar's Web Configuration Tool", but unfortunately the links are not valid anymore. The support of MaxLinear doesn't response to my case.

Do someone have experience with these ICs or with general USB control commands (CDC-ACM)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maxlinear has all of the Exar files online and just dumped into a directory.  You may be able to download the tool here:

https://www.maxlinear.com/Files/Documents/XR21B1411-OTP_Ver1103.zip